# How to delegate management of child context to parent

Tags: python, contextmanager

Let's say we've got an class 'A' that acts as a context manager in it's own right, so it implements the

```
def __enter__()
def __exit__()
```

interface. It's valid for client code to make 'A' objects directly using a `with` statement.

Now, we've also got another class 'B' that encapsulates other functionality, as well makes use of an 'A' object.

If we'd like to have 'B' act as a context manager as well, what's the right way of managing it's 'A' instance?

Should the implementation of `__enter__` and `__exit__` on 'B' call `__enter__` and `__exit__` (respectively) on it's A-object instance? Or is there a better way?

To give a concrete example (this is *not* what I'm using in my application, it's just the first non-abstract example that came to mind) consider two classes

- `DatabaseConnection`
- `DatabaseConnectionPool`

It's valid to use a single `DatabaseConnection` on it's own, thus `DatabaseConnection` implements the context-manager interface.

`DatabaseConnectionPool` makes use of several `DatabaseConnections` as well as other bits and bobs. Using `DatabaseConnectionPool` (i.e. "with") should do the set up and tear-down on it's `DatabaseConnection` instances (along with whatever else it might want to do)

**Update:**  I've written some test code which I was hoping would give the following output:

```
Enter invoked on Outer
Enter invoked on Inner
Within outer context...
do_foo invoked!
Still using outer...
Exit invoked on inner
Exit invoked on outer
Done using outer
```

but I got the following:

```
Enter invoked on Outer
Enter invoked on Inner
Exit invoked on inner
Within outer context...
do_foo invoked!
Still using outer...
Exit invoked on outer
Done using outer
```

Code:

```
class Inner(object):
  def __enter__(self):
    print "Enter invoked on Inner"
    return self

  def __exit__(self, typ, val, tb):
    print "Exit invoked on inner"

  def do_foo(self):
    print "do_foo invoked!"

class Outer(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._inner = Inner()

  def __enter__(self):
    print "Enter invoked on Outer"

    with self._inner as ctx:
      return self

  def __exit__(self, typ, val, tb):
    print "Exit invoked on outer"

with Outer() as outer:
  print "Within outer context..."
  outer._inner.do_foo()
  print "Still using outer..."

print "Done using outer"
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I've upvoted this, it was an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had the same design consideration, and ended up writing exit and enter functions in my 'child' classes, and only have the 'parent' class be a context manager.

(If I've understood your question correctly, which would be 'how can I elegantly also have all the classes that I've used in a context manager class close correctly when I've closed the parent context manager)

Answer (score 0):

It's really a design question and a judgment call. I'm going to suggest the following:

Pool class instance provides a context, which then programmatically uses DB connection instances as needed. But that would be a bit more complex than simply calling `__enter__` and `__exit__` for each DB instance, and I don't think you should attempt to do that, they're not intended for that purpose. In this case, I would suggest directly using the DB instance's context manager.

If you want to use their context managers, something like this would work:

```
def __enter__(self):
    for db in self.pool:
        with db as d:
            d.transaction()

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    pass
```

But if you want to error handle yourself:

```
def __enter__(self):
    for db in self.pool:
        try:
            db.connection()
            # ... write and transact here

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    if type is None: # no errors, so close as normal
        for db in self.pool:
            db.close()
    # ... more code here for proper error handling
```

Comment: 'A' is not a subclass of 'B', rather, 'B' _uses_ an instance of 'A' to do it's job.

Comment: Have updated my description to hopefully indicate better what it is I'm trying to achieve (composite context management)